# onActivityResult() does not change TextView (setText()) if rotated before startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, settext, screen-rotation, onactivityresult

This is kinda tricky. I have a profile `Fragment` and an 'Edit details' `Button` that opens a new `Activity` through `startActivityForResult()`.

In `onActivityResult()` I reload the `TextView`s with the new data after editing the info through `setText()`. It works fine.

**But** if I rotated the Profile Fragment prior to clicking the edit button, the `TextView`s won't display the new data after saving them. It seems like onSaveInstanceState() saves the `TextView` texts and won't let `onActivityResult()` change them...

Comment: Where do you keep the textview's new data?

Comment: In a db. I create a Cursor on onActivityResult() that brings the new data always and sets the TextViews. If the screen is not rotated, it works every time.

Comment: By the way, the ActionBar title DOES get changed.

Comment: After onActivityResult() I checked and tv.getText() gives me the new text... Is there any method called after it that restores the old data??

Comment: You'll need to restore it yourself.

Comment: I do! But it won't work...

Comment: Weeeell! I found out that if I call **EXACTLY** the same function from inside `onCreate()`, the view is updated correctly... But I have to do it from the ActionBar with `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`. So, I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Call setText() inside runOnUiThread...

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        display.setText("new text");
                    }
                });
```